# How to change the text after extract it in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, text

I'm working on my website to extract the data and I want to change text I actually want. I'm stored the website link in MYSQL database where I can output the link in PHP and I'm using PHP DOM to extract the data. I have extracted the text which I got "College Football "Texas Christian at Texas Tech" LIVE " using with this code:

```
<?php
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');

  $errmsg_arr = array();
  $errflag = false;
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if(!$link) 
  {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$db) 
  {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }

  function clean($var)
  {
    return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($var));
  }
  $channels = clean($_GET['channels']);
  $id = clean($_GET['id']);

  if($errflag) 
  {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    echo implode('<br />',$errmsg_arr);
  }
  else 
  {
    $insert = array();

    if(isset($_GET['channels'])) 
    {
      $insert[] = 'channels = \'' . clean($_GET['channels']) .'\'';
    }
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
    {
      $insert[] = 'id = \'' . clean($_GET['id']) . '\'';
    }


    if($channels && $id) 
    {
      $qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links FROM tvguide WHERE channels='$channels' && id='$id'";
      $result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
      {
        $links = $row['links'];
        include ('simple_html_dom.php');
        $html = file_get_html($links);
        $title1 = $html->find('a[id=rowTitle1]', 0); // with this
        echo $html->find('li[id=row1-3]', 0)->plaintext;
        echo "<BR></BR>";
      }
      mysql_close($link);
    }
  }
?>
```

Here's the HTML source after I extract it:

```
                        7:30 PM                              College Football                                              "Texas Christian at Texas Tech"                                                                                LIVE                          <BR></BR>
```

I can see in the HTML source that there are long space which I want to get rid it and I also want to ignore the time including AM and PM.

I want to change in the HTML source from this:

```
                        7:30 PM                              College Football                                              "Texas Christian at Texas Tech"                                                                                LIVE                          <BR></BR>
```

to this:

```
<span id='title1'>College Football: Texas Christian at Texas Tech - LIVE</span><br></br>
```

Could you please tell me how I can change the text I want using my current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

```
$test ='                        7:30 PM                              College Football                                              LIVE                          <BR></BR>';
//remove time hh:mm
$output = preg_replace('/\d:\d+/', '', $test);
$output = '<span id="title1">'.str_replace(array("\t", '   ', '<BR>','</BR>', 'AM','PM'), '', $output).'</span><br><br>';
$output = str_replace(' LIVE', '- LIVE', $output);

echo $output;
```

> College Football "Texas Christian at Texas Tech" - LIVE

It is not only visually "clean", but also "clean" in the resulting HTML (*but blanks should not matter for a reader, just for beautifying* - in fact, a reader *should* ignore blanks)

```
<span id="title1"> College Football "Texas Christian at Texas Tech" - LIVE  </span><br><br>
```

Comment: Updated the answer. If the time always is in `hh:mm`, that should be it (and no need for remove remaining `:` afterwards)

Comment: thanks for this, how I can get rid of the contain text which I want to change it from ' "' to replace it with ':' and also I want to replace the other text from '" LIVE' to replace it with '- LIVE'. How I can do this using your code?

Comment: yes, the code you post is almost done. The contain text is display 'College Football "Texas Christian at Texas Tech" LIVE'. I want to replace the contain text from ' "' to replace it with ': ' and also to replace the other text from '" LIVE' to replace it with ' - LIVE' to make it show it like this 'College Football: Texas Christian at Texas Tech - LIVE'. An idea?

Comment: Updated then, for the last time. I thought is was extremely obvious, not to be harsh :)